# HTML 5 works when directly loading the .html but not on Django or Node js server

Tags: django, node.js, html, video

I'm trying to get a video running on a web page, initially I tried the standard example I saw online by using:

```
<video src='video.mp4' controls></video>
```

When I double click on the .html file it opens in safari and works perfectly.

This however does not work when submitting that same line via a HttpResponse in Django or response.write in Node js.

After attempting several solutions I found online nothing worked, however I discovered something odd. By changing that same html src into a youtube video source (http://r13---sn kind), the video worked directly and in the Node and Django servers using the same exact method (just changing the src).

However, when downloading that exact same video from the source and specifying the path to where it as stored locally, it didn't work again... I have verified that the path is correct.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you show that path?

Comment: In django you probably want something like src="{{STATIC_URL}}video.mp4"  with {% load staticfiles %} at the top of the file. What happens in the django server? The video.mp4 file then will need to be store in the STATIC_DIRECTORY root.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can gather your problem is with the path if your running it locally then you will be going to `localhost` this means the video on the server is trying to load from `http://localhost/video.mp4` which wont work, in nodejs you can solve this by creating a file server with express.

```
var express = require("express"),
    path = require("path"),
    app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});
app.listen(port)
```

Directory structure:

```
- server.js
- index.html
- public/
    - video.mp4
- node_modules/
    - express/
```